# What to do if GUI has main yet implements functions of an existing CLI Java program which has its own main?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am in the process of creating a GUI, using Swing, for an existing Java project of mine. As the project was previously CLI-run, I have already created a main. The new JFRAME I have created also has its own main. Should I delete either?

Comment: Well, if you want to, you can. if you want to keep them both, you can, too.

Comment: You can specify which class should be executed for the command line (wrap it up in a script/bacth/exe wrapper) and the manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most IDEs detect when multiple main class are present and let you choose which one to use for the current session or permanently. And when you come to build and packaging you also still have the choice to define which class will be the actual main class of your jar (cf. `java -Dexec.mainClass` and/or `Manifest`). Hence no need to delete either.